# How to get full text of a tweet from Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to query tweets by a string, when I do this it returns tweets in a cutoff manner like "the quick brown fox ju..."

How do I get the full text of the tweet?

here is part of my code

```
def get_tweets(self, query, count = 10):

    #this is main function that will query for 
    #a specified number of tweets

    #an empty list to store parsed tweets
    tweets = []

    a = self.api.get_status(912886007451676672, tweet_mode='extended')

    try:
        #call the api to fetch tweets
        fetched = self.api.search(q = query, rpp = int(count), tweet_mode="extended")

        #parsing tweets one by one
        for tweet in fetched:
            #empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet
            parsed_tweet = {}

            #saving text of tweet in dictionary
            parsed_tweet['text'] = self.api.get_status(tweet.id, tweet_mode='extended')._json['full_text']
            #saving the sentiments of the tweet
            parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.full_text)
            parsed_tweet['subjectivity'] = self.get_tweet_subjectivity(tweet.full_text)
            #appending parsed tweet to tweets list
            #and only append once if there are rebtweets
            if tweet.retweet_count > 0:
                if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
            else:
                tweets.append(parsed_tweet)

        return tweets

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Error : " + str(e))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you see [this](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/935#issuecomment-333410681) GitHub comment? If so did accessing `extended_tweet` instead of `full_text` not work?

Comment: yea I saw that comment, I'm trying to access extended_tweet but its not working

Comment: Also, that's good info to have put in your original question - however, I think saying it's "not working" is too vague. At least including _why_ it's not working would be really helpful.

Comment: Ok well the tweets are still being truncated even when I access the extended_tweet dictionary and calling its full_text key as seen above in the code, as for why it's not working I can't really answer that can I, else I wouldn't have asked about it on here?

Comment: I meant that saying "it's not working" is too vague - you may no know the cause, but the least you can do is explain what's happening instead of what you want - like, if there's an error, what the error is, or in your case, that the tweets are still truncated.

Comment: There are two types of JSONs, different for a new tweet and retweeted tweet. Inside the retweeted tweet's JSON, the original tweet's data is nested inside retweeted_status attribute.The full_text  attribute that the retweeted JSON has is usually truncated, therefore you need to extract the full_text of the nested orginal tweet.This might be your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full_text attribute with extended mode